# Is there any evidence that physical appearance and temperament are coinherited together in humans?

Tags: genetics

Recently my wife and I had our second child, and I've noticed a trend with the two. Our first looks a lot like me, similar facial features and head shape, and along with it he also seems to hold many of my behavioral traits. Now with our second we're seeing the opposite, he looks a lot like mom (facial features and head shape) and so far he seems to have many of her behavioral traits, but none of mine.

My question is: have any studies discovered that appearance and temperament are (at least partially) inherited together? Has it been proven that a child who looks more like one parent, will likely behave more similarly to that parent?

Comment: Very interesting question, but I suspect the true answer is going to be exceptionally hard to find out. Disentangling the effects of shared environment and genetics on social traits in humans is a very very tricky problem.

Comment: No solid evidence as to linkage of appearance and personality traits, but there is some evidence of linkages of physical appearance and some medical aspects of health, e.g. cardiovascular fitness. But there’s plenty of evidence - solid - that many “personality traits” are heritable, and present from birth. I suspect it’s possible but not probable.

Comment: @user438383 anecdotal, but in my experience very specific traits are directly heritable - extraversion, memory capacity, language capacity, deductive ability. Essentially traits that are dictated by brain shape and structure.

Comment: When you say "in my experience" - do you mean in the twin-studies that you've read about?

Comment: Basic observation of parents/children, I've also got a bit of neurophys under my belt. I get that people at this stack won't like an unevidenced comment. The way I see it is that brain structure offers the basic framework, or template, for temperament. Environmental experience then interacts with that structure.